# What's the point on increasing the Int or Ma stat if the MC can't use magic?

Tags: soul-hackers

Unlike Nemissa, the protagonist can’t use magic of any kind. What’s the point in increasing any of these stats then? Does any of these help magic defense, summoning time or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intelligence**

The Intelligence stat causes your magic to hit enemies more often and also means you'll be taking less damage from magical attacks aimed at you.

**Magic**

This stat causes your Magical attacks to become stronger, but, unlike Intelligence above, Magic does not affect your Magical Defense.

in [soul-hackers](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/devil-summoner-soul-hackers/Stats)